# Using a triac plus an H-bridge to switch DC or AC

Tags: ac, dc, multiplexer, triac

I've been working on a controller for inductive loads, and I want the system to be compatible with either DC or AC loads. I've got a 24V to 34V DC boost regulator powering an H-bridge, which is creating a sine wave OR just sending out straight DC. Now I want to multiplex this output to eight separate channels using a triac or similar device. I've already looked into using more half bridges or using SSRs. Both are too expensive for my application.

My question is, can I use triacs in this application to switch either the DC or the AC output from the two half bridges? I understand that triacs can only be turned "on" in DC, but if I can control the H-bridge, could I disable the output to turn the triac off?